# Easy GUI subversion server and client for Ubuntu natty

Tags: svn, ubuntu-11.04

Can you please suggest which subversion client and server will be easy for beginner in ubuntu natty to work with and how to install.

I got some idea like Nautilussvn ,Rapidsvn ..

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try RabbitVCS (like TortoiseSVN for windows), it works in older versions (but not sure this one)

Run:

```
  sudo apt-get update
```

And install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-core rabbitvcs-nautilus rabbitvcs-thunar rabbitvcs-gedit rabbitvcs-cli
```

Then to install subversion itself (which I think is the best solution)

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Answer (score 1):

[uberSVN](http://www.uberSVN.com/) has a great web interface for the server admin side but not sure about the best client

Comment: I know natty works but I'm not sure if it's on the official supported platforms list yet.  They'll support it just the same on svnforum.org

Answer (score 0):

You can use subclipse (if you are using eclipse) it would be the same as it is in windows.
As for the server, Google-ing will show you lots of results where you can choose a server based on your preference (public/private , free/cheap/expensive ... etc) I tried googlecode which is free for opensource projects ... and Assembla in which you can get free private spaces and can pay extra for other services.